# Backbone Collections Undefined

Tags: backbone.js, collections

In my database, I am simply trying to grab every object from my "countries" array, however when I run it, the console tells me that my collections is undefined.

---

### index.js

```
  var Backbone = require('backbone')

  var App = require('./app.js')
  var countryCollection = require('./collections/countries');
  var countryModel = require('./models/country')
  var countryView = require('./views/country-bio');
  App.Views.CountryBio  = new CountryBioView;

  App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      'bio.html(/)': 'index',
      '*actions': 'defaultRoute'
    },

      index: function() {
        console.log(countryCollection)
        console.log('this works')
        },

        defaultRoute: function() {
            console.log("404 Page Not Found")
        }

  })

  App.Router = new App.Router;

  Backbone.history.start();
```

---

### Collections

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');

var App = require('../app');
var Country = require('../models/country');**strong text**

var CountryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/countries',
  model: Country
});

App.Collections.country = new CountryCollection;

module.exports = App.Collections.country;
```

---

### Models

var Backbone = require('backbone');

```
var App = require('../app');

App.Models.Country = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return 'http://localhost:3000/countries';
  }
});

module.exports = App.Models.Country;
```

---

### Views

```
 var $ = require('jquery');
 var Backbone = require('backbone');
 var countryBioTemplate = require('../templates/countryBio.hbs'); 

var App = require('../app');

var CountryBio = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('main'),

  collection: App.Collections.country,

  render: function () {
    var _this = this;
    var countryCollection = this.collection;
    console.log(countryCollection)

    // Fetch Collection from Server
  //   countryCollection.fetch().done(function (country) {
  //     _this.$el.html(countryBioTemplate(country));
  //   });
  }
});

module.exports = CountryBio;
```

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Sorry, jumped the gun on the stack overflow usage.

Comment: If you think the problem is something other users are likely to have then you should add your solution as an answer. If it's just something simple that isn't likely to be reproduced (like a typo for example) then the question should probably be closed.